# Contruct a homomorphism $\phi$ of $(\mathbb{Q}, +)$ such that $\mathrm{Ker} \phi = (\mathbb{Z}, +)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> $1)$ Contruct a homomorphism $\phi$ of $(\mathbb{Q}, +)$ such that
>   $\mathrm{Ker} \phi = (\mathbb{Z}, +)$.
>
> $2)$ Show that the order of $(\mathbb{Q}, +)/\mathrm{Ker} \phi$ is
>   infinite, but all its elements have finite order.

I'm having trouble with $2)$.

**Attempt:**

$1)$ Consider the map $\phi: (\mathbb{Q}, +) \to (\mathbb{C}, \cdot)$ given by $\phi(r) = e^{i2\pi r}$, where $(\mathbb{C}, \cdot)$ represents the multiplicative group of the $n$ roots of unity.

$(\ast)\ \phi$ is a homomorphism:

For any $r_1, r_2 \in (\mathbb{Q}, +)$ we have that

\begin{align}
\phi(r_1 + r_2) &= e^{i2\pi (r_1 + r_2)}\\
&= e^{i2\pi r_1}\cdot e^{i2\pi r_2}\\
&= \phi(r_1)\cdot \phi(r_2)
\end{align}

$(\ast)\ \phi$ is surjective (this is not asked in the first part of the question, but I thought it would be useful or answering the second part).

Let $e^{i2\pi r} \in  (\mathbb{C}, \cdot)$. Since the $n$ roots of unity are given by $\cos (\frac{2\pi k}{n}) + i\sin (\frac{2\pi k}{n})$, with $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $k \in (1, n-1)$ it follows that $r$ has the form $r = \frac{mk}{n}$ for some $m \in \mathbb{Z}$. Thus we have that $r = \frac{mk}{n} \in \mathbb{Q}$. So $\phi$ is surjective.

Let find the kernel.

\begin{align}
\mathrm{Ker}\phi &= \{r \in (\mathbb{Q}, +): \phi (r) = 1 \}\\
&= \{r \in (\mathbb{Q}, +): e^{i2\pi r} = 1 \}
\end{align}

$$\implies e^{i2\pi r} =  \cos (2\pi r) + i\sin (2\pi r) = 1$$

\begin{align}
\implies \cos (2\pi r) &= 1\\
2\pi r &= 2\pi l \qquad l \in \mathbb{Z}\\
r &= l \hspace{30pt} l \in \mathbb{Z}
\end{align}

So

\begin{align}
\mathrm{Ker}\phi &= \{r \in (\mathbb{Q}, +): \phi (r) = 1 \}\\
&= \{r \in (\mathbb{Q}, +): r \in \mathbb{Z} \}\\
&= (\mathbb{Z}, +)
\end{align}

$2)$ From the previous part, by the Theorem of Homomorphisms we have that

$$(\mathbb{Q}, +)/\mathrm{Ker}\phi \cong (\mathbb{C}, \cdot)$$

$\implies |(\mathbb{Q}, +)/ \mathrm{Ker}\phi| = |(\mathbb{C}, \cdot)| = n$. But $n$ is fixed so it's finite, not infinite as it should. And

**How do I show that each element has finite order?**

A coset $\in (\mathbb{Q}, +)/\mathrm{Ker}\phi$ has the form $\frac{k}{n} + \mathbb{Z}$. So, to my understanding, if I pick for instance $\frac{k}{n} = \frac{1}{2}$, then $\frac{1}{2} + \mathbb{Z} = \Big \{..., -\frac{3}{2}, -\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{3}{2},...\Big\}$. So how does it suppose that $|\frac{1}{2} + \mathbb{Z}|  < \infty$ ?

Comment: You should not use $(\mathbb{C},\cdot)$ to mean "the multiplicative group of the $n$ roots of unity." For one thing, you haven't said what $n$ is. For another, the set in question is not equal to $\mathbb{C}.$ You need to properly define what group you are referring to before anything else: give a proper description of the elements in the set, give the set a name ($G$ will do), and then write $(G,\cdot)$ if this is your preferred notation.

Comment: $\phi$ is not surjective, the image is the set of complex numbers $z$ such that $\mid z \mid=1$. If you call $S^1$ the set of complex numbers of norm 1, you can see this set form a multiplicative group.

Answer (score 1):

What is $n$? There is no fixed $n$ here. Your homomorphism simply takes a rational number $r$ to $e^{2\pi ir}$. The image is the $n$th roots of unity for all $n$, which is an infinite group. Thus the first isomorphism theorem tells you that $(\mathbb{Q}, +)/\ker\phi$ is infinite. But if $z \in (\mathbb{C}, \cdot)$, then $z = e^{2\pi i r}$ for some $r \in \mathbb{Q}$. Write $r = m/n$ with $\gcd(m,n) = 1$. Then $z$ has order $n$ in $(\mathbb{C}, \cdot)$.

Answer (score 1):

Finite order does not mean that the coset is finite.

It means that for every $q \in \mathbb Q$, there is $n\in \mathbb N^*$ such that $n(q +\mathbb Z)=0$.

If $q=\pm\frac ab$, with $a,b \in \mathbb N$, then we can take $n=b$.

Comment: Since $q + \mathbb{Z} = \{x\in \mathbb{Q}: x = q + t \ \text{for some}\ t \in \mathbb{Z}\}$. Thus $\forall\ q \in \mathbb{Q} \to n(q+t) = 0\quad t \in \mathbb{Z}$. But how do I find explicitly that $n$? To me either $n = 0$ which is not possible if $n \in \mathbb{N}$ or $q = -t$, but this doesn't happen for every $\ q \in \mathbb{Q}$ (since $t$ is an integer).